# Woocommerce: how to wc_add_order_item_meta on woocommerce_add_to_cart hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Use case:

1. user will choose the date for product from the list and add the
   product to cart by button
2. woocommerce_add_to_cart will trigger and
3. the date append to item as meta by wc_add_order_item_meta

   ```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_event_date_meta',  10, 3 );

   function add_event_date_meta($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity) {
      $event_date = get_cart_item_event_date();
      $result = wc_add_order_item_meta( $product_id, '_event_date', $event_date);
   }
   ```

The $result is valid id, but no '_event_date' meta is included in a checkout cart item. Is there something I do not understand properly? Meta key should be added to cart item while I recieved the id of it, or?

Comment: You can't add order item meta when there isn't yet an order item. Check out my [tutorial](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) on custom checkout fields. Check the "Save the extra data on checkout" section.

Comment: @helgatheviking … May be I am wrong but I think that this is related to product custom fields, **but not custom checkout fields.** The Op submit first this data with the add-to-cart button. Then he needs to save this data in the cart object first, then he will be able to get it from cart to the related order item.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you are right. I have a [tutorial for that too!](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-product/). Either way, you can't add order item meta when there is no order item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking)  and [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) for yours comments. The solution I found in [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking)'s [tutorial](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-product/). This is exactly what I was searching for:

```
    /*
     * Add custom data to the cart item
     * @param array $cart_item
     * @param int $product_id
     * @return array
     */
    function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){
       if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ) {
          $cart_item['custom_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] );
       }
       return $cart_item;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'kia_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
```